# Debugging 500 Error on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Hope someone can help me. I have tried all of the following solutions:

- Send error to browser is true
- Error mode Detailed
- Enable parents path is true

But still the IIS is loading the file [Errors/500.aspx](http://pastebin.com/kUbFEJYR) that is in the project folder and I cannot debug the error.

This is my [Web.config](http://pastebin.com/9bgnfmFp) file. Even if custom error mode is Off it's still loading custom Errors/500.aspx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your browser is configured to show errors, like in IE:

- Turn off the friendly error message option in the browser as follows:

  - In Internet Explorer, on the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
  - On the Advanced tab, under the Browsing section, click to clear the Show friendly HTTP error messages check box, and then click OK.
  - Close the browser.

Turn on detailed errors in IIS.

- Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager —> Your Web Site —> Error Pages -> Edit Feature Settings -> select "Detailed errors"

Make sure your web.config does not have any nodes like:

```
<httpErrors>
       <error statusCode="500" path="/somedir/500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

and

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/404error.aspx" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did all the following already. After the error I'm always redirected to the file Errors/500.aspx.

Comment: take a look at your web.config, i appended these issues to my answer

Comment: Thanks @Semaphore. I have updated my question with a link to my web.config file. It doesn't contain any of the nodes you outlined.

Comment: Check your global.asax for any re-directs in it when there is an error.

Comment: And look in your http handler to see if any redirects are happening. I guess you can search the whole solution for "500.aspx".

Comment: Thanks @Semaphore. You lead me to the solution. Actually there was a ErrorsLog.aspx file inside a subfolder that was showing the error. Still don't how the error is routed here, as I didn't write the code, but at least I could debug and solve the issue.